# x3dom - how to make zoom buttons?

Tags: javascript, zooming, x3dom, x3d

How to zoom in/out typical (like this: http://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/basics/hello/HelloX3DOM.html) x3d scene without mouse wheel? Is it possible to create +/- zoom buttons like on google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function zoom (delta) {
 var x3d = document.getElementById("x3dElement");
 var vpt = x3d.getElementsByTagName("viewpoint")[0];
 vpt.fieldOfView = parseFloat(vpt.fieldOfView) + delta;
}
</script>
```

And the html buttons:

```html
<button onclick="zoom(-0.15)">Zoom in</button>
<button onclick="zoom(0.15)">Zoom out</button>
```

That's it.

Comment: Note that changing the FoV might distort the objects